# Sed replace unusual file extension arising from gmv

Tags: macos, sed

As a result of using gmv on a large nested directory to flatten in,  I have a number of duplicate files separated out and with the extensions "._1_"    "._2_"  etc  ( ....  ._n_  )

eg `"a.pdf.\_1\_"`

ie its

a(dot)pdf(dot)(back slash)1(back slash)

as opposed to

a(dot)pdf(dot)1

which I want to reduce it back to "a.pdf"

I tried something like

```
sed -i .bak  "s|.\_1\_||" *
```

which is usually reliable and doesn't require escape characters.   However its giving me 
"error: illegal byte sequence"

Grateful for help to fix.  This is on Mac OSX  terminal.  Ideally I'd like a generic solution to fix ._*_  forms where the * varies 1 to 9

Comment: You can't rename files using sed. Refer to [Renaming filename before first occurrence of character](//stackoverflow.com/a/59117422) or other similar questions

Comment: I'm trying this but its not working.....  grateful for help                                    #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                 

for fp in ./*._*_ ; do

echo $fp

insertString=""

cutString="._1_"

$outputFile="${fp/$cutString/$insertString}"

echo mv "$fp" "$outputFile"

done

Comment: Please edit your Q with your best attempt to solve your problem. Reading in comments is difficult, and it just provokes long strings of comments that readers must plow thru to understand your problem. Use the `{}` from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are two challenges here.

- How to deal with the duplicate `basename` (The suffixes '*1*', '*2*', ... mostly like added to designate different sections of a single file - may be different pages a PDF, etc. Performing rename that will strip the files may cause some important files to disappear.
- How to deal with the `"error: illegal byte sequence"` which indicate that some special characters (unicode) are part of the file name. Usually ASCII characters with value >= `\0xc0`, which can not be decoded according to the current local. The fact that the file names are escaped (as per OP `"a.pdf.\_1\_"` may hint at additional characters, not displayed (assuming this was not added by the OP).

Proposed solution is to rename the file, and place the 'sequence' part, that make the file unique BEFORE the extension, allowing the extension to be used to determine file type.

> a.pdf.*1* => a.*1*.pdf

The rename command to perform this task is:

> rename 's/(.*).pdf.(_.*_)/$1$2.pdf/' *.pdf._*_

Adjust the file name list as needed, and use `-n` to verify before running.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable percaution until you are sure that you only need one file. (are they all the same size?) . To answer the specific Q of removing trailing sequence info, you can use `echo mv "$fn"  "${fn%.\\_[0-9]\\_}"` (and remove `echo` if it is working as you expect). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
rename -n s/.\_1\_//  *.*_1_
```

works (remove the -n  once tested).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13         I noticed the edits to this showing after the rename command  \\*.\\*\\_1\\_          It should remain  \*.\*\_1\_    as this is the command line bash expansion to select the specific files.

Comment: I apologies if I missed something here. I actually only wrapped up your solution in CODE TAGS. You could edit it, only thing is make sure it is in CODE TAGS.No technical aspect was changed from my side(if something wrongly/unintentionally happened then I am sorry for it).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 no problems - I'm not familiar with code tags (till now :-)  )   anyhow the solution reedited to display perfectly now.